# Prove or disprove: For every number $s \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ there is a $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $s+t \in \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, irrational-numbers

> Prove or disprove: For every number $s \in \mathbb{R} \setminus
> \mathbb{Q}$ there is a $t \in \mathbb{R}$ with $s+t \in \mathbb{Q}$.

First of all, I thought what exactly means $s\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$.
I think it means all numbers $\in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{Q}$.

So what will remain to use then? The irrational numbers.

Let $s=\sqrt{2}$ and let $t=0$. The result will be $\sqrt{2}$ which is $\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Thus the statement is wrong.

---

Did I do everything correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The statement is correct. One (of many) very simple way of doing this is taking $t=-s$.

Comment: Indeed. @cnmesr : The main mistake is that you confuse "there is a $t$" (which you can choose, as in the answer above) with "for all $t$" (and you correctly disproved this statement, but it's not your question).

Comment: Oh I misunderstood the task.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

You have not disproved the statement.

The statement is: "For every irrational number $s$, there is *some* number $t$ such that $s+t$ is rational," not ". . . for *every* number $t$, $s+t$ is rational." If you want to disprove the statement, you need to find some irrational $s$ such that *no matter* what $t$ you pick, $s+t$ is always irrational.

This will be difficult to do, since the statement is in fact true. HINT: given $s$, can you think of a number which when added to $s$ gives $0$? How about $2$? Or ${1\over 3}$? Or . . .

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification! Misunderstood the task :(

Comment: By the way, by difficult you mean impossible? Or is it really possible to make a true statement like that wrong by proving? :o

Comment: @cnmesr I mean impossible. :)

Answer (score 1):

Let s be irrational number.

Take t=-s .

Then s+t=0.

Comment: This answer is OK, but it does not add anything to the existing answers.